# Duplicate Schema.org content on same page

Tags: schema.org

I am currently setting up Schema.org content on multiple sites.
They are using the `LocalBusiness` type and have `telephone`/`address` both in the header and footer.

When setting up Schema.org on both sections and testing, I get 2 `LocalBusiness` returned with the same content.

Does this affect in any way the Schema.org? Would it be better to only have it pull 1 section instead of 2?

Answer (score 1):

With Microdata/RDFa, you are not annotating your page’s content. You are just using your content/markup as "carrier" to provide structured data.

If the telephone number of the local business appears several times on the same page, there’s no need to mark it up with Microdata/RDFa several times: you only need it one time for the consumers that make use of your structured data.

So don’t provide two `LocalBusiness` items on the same page, if both really represent the same local business.